# How to add a DropDownList column to GridView? Visual web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, visual-studio, spgridview

How can I add a `DropDownList` column to gridview in code behind? In my case a want to add a dropdown called `Employer`. I have successfully added 1 string column called `Name` with the following code:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DropDownList drp = new DropDownList();

  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Employer", typeof(DropDownList));

  drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("test", "0"));

  foreach (SPListItem item in queryResults)
  {

      dr["Name"] = item["iv3h"].ToString();
      dr["Employer"] = drp;
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }

   BoundField bf = new BoundField();
   bf.DataField = "Name";
   bf.HeaderText = "Name";
   bf.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
   bf.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
   GridViewEarningLine.Columns.Add(bf);
```

The `Name` column is working wonderful but the `Employer` is showing this message in each row `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`.

I DON'T HAVE ACCESS TO ASPX PAGE SO I CANNOT ADD IT WITH `TemplateField`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, **`Visual Web Part`** has a code behind so you can add ASP.Net control like Gridview and add your dropdown list control to a template field as shown below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
                 </asp:DropDownList>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

**Second**, you will need to bind the dropdown list in `RowDataBound` as shown below

```
   protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList dropcontrol = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl");
             foreach (SPListItem item in queryResults)
                dropcontrol .Items.Add( item["columnName"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

---

Regarding ordering check [How to reorder columns in grid-view dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976153/how-to-reorder-columns-in-gridview-dynamically)

Comment: But due that all columns are are added with code behind if I do this the dropdown will be displayed in the first column. How can i reorder columns because I want this dropdown to be in the last column?

Comment: Please add the code that add the columns from code behind to can help you faster

Comment: finally is working

Comment: But when I post I set the `AutoPostBack=true` the dropdown disappears, why? how to prevent it.

Comment: do you have any event in the dropdown list? if no no need for post back if yes try to use update panel